# CakePHP method visibility

Tags: cakephp, visibility

I am a little bit confused right now...in the CakePHP documentation, it states that PHP's visibility can be replaced as follows: `private` with `__` and `protected` with `_`. But doing the necessary replacements, and calling a `private` method from within another class leads to the execution of that method without any restriction. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you setting these private methods in a controller or a model? Because the naming convention only works on controllers as far as I know. Also I believe it only works if someone tries to access it from a URL like www.example.com/controller/_protectecAction

Comment: I am setting them in a model, but if they only work for URL access, why would there be a `protected` and `private` equivalent?

Comment: I have no idea, it's just the way cake works, if its in the model just set private and protected on it, since the _ only works for the controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're setting them in the model, just use private and protected, the _ and __ only work for controller actions

Comment: But it doesn't make sense. Why would it work only for controllers? Also, there is nowhere specified that the `_` and `__` are restricted or "work" just under certain circumstances...

Comment: From the cookbook: http://book.cakephp.org/view/904/Controller-Conventions 
It says there that the _ and __ are used for denying external access but permitting internal use

Comment: So according to this like I said you could just use the private and protected tags for your methods and variables as you would normally use them, since the _ and __ are simply CakePHP conventions and do not act in place of private and protected

Comment: I will do so, but I am still confused regarding this aspect. The article you cited refers only to `_`, it says nothing about `__`. Thank you for your answer, however, I will still let the question open for further any other pertinent answer.

Comment: Ok, sure thing, I'm reading up about this on the CakePHP google group and everything seems to indicate the normal use of private and protected and that the _ is only for blocking navigation to said actions http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/c8da286e91748241/02a9a9f505e7a962?lnk=gst&q=private+protected#02a9a9f505e7a962 also I can't find any mention of __ where did you read about this convention initially?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will go with the `private` and `protected` keywords.

Answer (score 2):

the underscore is only effective for controller method, since the user can't access it. Inside Cake app, it's really just a convention. Besides I don't think it's a problem: You only need to lock your house from outside, you don't need to lock every doors if you are the only one in it. If you want to achieve that use `private` and `protected` PHP keywords.

Comment: I'll then go with the `private` and `protected` keywords. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using _ and __ for protected resp. private methods is a CakePHP convention because CakePHP (up to v1.3.x) is still a PHP4 framework and PHP4 doesn't have the `protected` and `private` keywords. This means, that even if you prefix your method names in such a way, they are still public methods as far as PHP is concerned.

In your application I would follow the approach used by the coming CakePHP 2: use the naming convention together with the respective visibility keyword. For example, a private method would then be defined as `private function __myPrivateMethod()`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will do so and hence be prepared for CakePHP 2.